# How do I fix Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\proxies_priv' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

Tags: mysql, xampp

Switching on my system this morning, MySQL immediately stops once started in XAMPP, windows 10. Last thing I did was install Windows Powertoys, not sure if it's the cause but it's the last change.

I found the subject-quoted error in Windows event viewer log but following Google searches for resolutions I see to run myisamchk: this gives me the error proxies_priv.mai is not a myisam table.

How can I get things back to normal?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem here.
You are getting the error `proxies_priv.mai is not a myisam table` because you typed the file name wrong. It's `proxies_priv.MYI`, not `proxies_priv.mai`.

Nevertheless, trying to fix it by `./myisamchk.exe -r ../data/mysql/proxies_priv.MYI` seems not working for me. I got `proxies_priv doesn't have a correct index definition.` and don't know what to do next.

Finally I deleted all the file in mysql data folders containing `proxies_priv` and at least got mysql running.
According to [apachefriends post](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=79199)

> Everything seems to work. I'm not entirely sure what those tables are used for, since I never used any proxy with my local mysql server.